# Node findById() crashing on invalid id only: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ok so I have a basic `GET` method for returning a 'genre' based on an id in a `MongoDB` database and being called by `Mongoose`.
This works just fine when the id is valid but as soon as it is invalid it crashed my application.

My code:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const genre = await Genre.findById(req.params.id);
    if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);
    res.send(genre);
});

// Helper Functions

function genreNotFoundError(res) {
    res.status(404).send('Genre not found');
}
```

Here's the request and body:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/genres/5ac68d7d7d113ded8c36f3fc

{
    "_id": "5ac68d7d7d113ded8c36f3fc",
    "name": "Drama",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The crash occurs at the point at which the `_id` field is changed, as below:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/genres/1234
```

This gives me the below error.

I have tried using `findByOne({_id: req.params.id})` as suggested in other posts but that does not seem to do anything.

Error:

```
(node:70853) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1234" at path "_id" for model "Genre"
    at new CastError (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:27:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:724:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1095:15)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:198:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1064:15)
    at cast (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:300:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3208:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1280:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1496:8)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/richardcurteis/Development/Courses/NodeJsCourse/vidly-node/node_modules/kareem/index.js:311:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:70853) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:70853) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add proper error handling to the db call:

```
 router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
   const genre = await Genre.findById(req.params.id);
   if(!genre) return genreNotFoundError(res);
   res.send(genre);
  } catch(e) {
    return genreNotFoundError(res);
  }
});
```

Comment: That did work. I had to extract the logic from `genreNotFound` as I got an error, `ReferenceError: genreNotFound is not defined`.

Is there something funny going on with the context in the catch block?

Comment: @rich oops no that was a typo :) `genreNotFound` != `genreNotFoundError`

Comment: @rich glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Jonas W sums that up. There is another way you can do this by using [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

Something like

```
if(!validator.isMongoId(req.params.id)){
res.send("invalid id ")
} else ...//handle your request
```